# Executing an effect when the user clicks on an element every time

Tags: jquery, html, css

How I can Execute this effect every time the user clicks on the element with jquery?

I add a ripple class on click but when I click on the element in the second time its can't execute because the class is already added how I can fix this issue?

```
<div class="circle-ripple"></div>
```

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #4e4e4e;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

}

.circle-ripple {
  background-color: #35ffc3;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.ripple {
    -webkit-animation: ripple 0.7s linear;
          animation: ripple 0.7s linear;
  animation-duration:0.5s;

}
@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 1em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 3em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 5em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 3em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 5em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 8em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 1em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 3em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 5em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 3em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 5em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 8em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0);
  }
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".circle-ripple").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("ripple");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid timeouts you can instead reinsert the element like so (I only changed the JavaScript):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".circle-ripple").click(function(){
      // reinsert div with ripple class
      const new_element = $(this).clone(true);
      new_element.addClass("ripple");
      $(this).before(new_element);
      $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #4e4e4e;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

}

.circle-ripple {
  background-color: #35ffc3;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.ripple {
    -webkit-animation: ripple 0.7s linear;
          animation: ripple 0.7s linear;
  animation-duration:0.5s;

}
@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 1em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 3em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 5em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 3em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 5em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 8em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 1em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 3em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 5em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 3em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 5em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 8em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-ripple"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` will be a better option i guess

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".circle-ripple").click(function(){
    var data = $(this)
    data.addClass("ripple");
     setTimeout(function() {
        data.removeClass('ripple');
    }, 500)
    
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #4e4e4e;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

}

.circle-ripple {
  background-color: #35ffc3;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.ripple {
    -webkit-animation: ripple 0.7s linear;
          animation: ripple 0.7s linear;
  animation-duration:0.5s;

}
@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 1em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 3em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 5em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 3em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 5em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 8em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 1em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 3em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 5em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 3em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 5em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 8em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle-ripple"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the class after a certain timeout.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".circle-ripple").click(function(){
    var selector = $(this);
    selector.addClass("ripple");
    setTimeout(function() { 
      selector.removeClass("ripple");
      }, 2000);
  });
});
```

Set the timeout value as your desire. Hope this Helps.

the answer is edited after the comment from Nuhman.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but using `this` inside `setTimeout` has got some problems. You need to click twice after the first click for the animation to kick in. Get reference to the element outside `setTimeout` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55951247/5330419) answer.